# Why the id of view from getview () is different in onViewCreated() and onActivityCreated()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tested with the following code in Fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_test, container, false)
    Log.d("m", "onCreateView view id: ${view.id}")
    Log.d("m", "onCreateView view hash: ${view.hashCode()}")
    Log.d("m", "onCreateView get view id: ${getView()?.id}")
    Log.d("m", "onCreateView get view hash: ${getView()?.hashCode()}")
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("m", "onViewCreated view id: ${view.id}")
    Log.d("m", "onViewCreated view hash: ${view.hashCode()}")
    Log.d("m", "onViewCreated get view id: ${getView()?.id}")
    Log.d("m", "onViewCreated get view hash: ${getView()?.hashCode()}")
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("m", "onActivityCreated get view id: ${getView()?.id}")
    Log.d("m", "onActivityCreated get view hash: ${getView()?.hashCode()}")
}
```

The results are shown below. You can see that their hashcodes are the same. But id has changed in onActivityCreated(). Is that why?

```
onCreateView view id: 2131230839
onCreateView view hash: 211623483
onCreateView get view id: null
onCreateView get view hash: null
onViewCreated view id: 2131230839
onViewCreated view hash: 211623483
onViewCreated get view id: **2131230839**
onViewCreated get view hash: 211623483
onActivityCreated get view id: **2131230981**
onActivityCreated get view hash: 211623483
```

Comment: How are you adding your fragment? Is it via a `<fragment>` tag?

Comment: thanks! I got it. The id of the fragment is replaced by the id in the fragment tag in the activity layout. And I want to know where this replacement process happened, can this be seen?